# How to fix "cy.find() failed because this element is detached from the DOM"?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I wrote the code to find each element in a loop and click delete within the item if they exist on the page. However, If there are more than 3 objects then the code throws error. Please suggest me a fix as I'm pointless how to fix this after trying various different scenarios.

Here is my code:

```
cy.get('.row.js-all-talking-points-container').find('.card.obm-card-secondary.obm-card-agenda.h-100.mx-3.mx-sm-0').each(($el, index, $list) => {

    const getTextobjective = $el.find('span.agenda-item-title.text-muted').text()
    if (getTextobjective.includes('Objectives'))
    {
        cy.wrap($el).find('.btn.btn-outline-primary.js-remove-talking-point.js-remove-handler-added').should('be.visible').click({force: true});
    }
 })
```

I tried to find each object in the page and if it exists then get locator of delete button in each objects then delete those items but I get an error:

> cy.find() failed because this element is detached from the DOM

Answer (score 2):

You can fix detached error by re-querying the detached element.

Also, loop is simpler (no `if()` required) if you pre-filter on the text contains "Objectives".

```js
cy.get('.row.js-all-talking-points-container')
  .find('.card.obm-card-secondary.obm-card-agenda.h-100.mx-3.mx-sm-0')
  .filter(':contains(Objectives)')     
  .each(($el, index) => {

    // fresh query of .card each time in the loop
    cy.get('.card.obm-card-secondary.obm-card-agenda.h-100.mx-3.mx-sm-0')
      .filter(':contains(Objectives)')  
      .eq(index)
      .find('.btn.btn-outline-primary.js-remove-talking-point.js-remove-handler-added')
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
    }
  })
```

or use an alias, will also fix detached error

```js
cy.get('.row.js-all-talking-points-container')
  .find('.card.obm-card-secondary.obm-card-agenda.h-100.mx-3.mx-sm-0')
  .filter(':contains(Objectives)')    
  .as('objectiveCards')                          // set alias here
  .each(($el, index) => {

    // use alias here to fix detached error
    cy.get('@objectiveCards')
      .eq(index)
      .find('.btn.btn-outline-primary.js-remove-talking-point.js-remove-handler-added')
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
    }
  })
```